# Bind Action not working outside of the partialview

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

When I take away from the PartialView the click action jquery, the code stop working:

Partial View:

```
@model Heelp.ViewModels.CategoryGetAllBySearchListViewModel

<p class="float-left margin-top align-left"><span>Encontrámos <em><a href="#">@Model.TotalSearchCount</a></em> resultados nas categorias:</span></p>
<div class="clear-both">
    <div id="searchResultsList" class="float-left">
        <ul>
            @foreach (var item in Model.CategoryGetAllBySearch)
            {
                <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink(
                        String.Format("{0} {1} ver »", item.SearchCount, item.Name),
                        MVC.Company.GetAllByCategory(item.Id, Model.Search, Model.Location, Model.IsCenterFromUser, Model.CenterLng, Model.CenterLat, Model.SearchRadius),
                        new { id = "getCompanies" })
                </li>
            }        
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script>

$("#getCompanies").on("click", function() 
{
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            companyGetAllByCategoryOnSuccess(result);
        }
    });

    return false;
});

</script>
```

If I put the script code in an external JS file, the code don't work, why?

Thanks.

Comment: what doesn't work? also, did you make sure the external JS is referenced from the page?

Comment: try wraping you jquery in onready function

Comment: @Forte hi, If the script is not in the page, the actionlink returns a new page with the text result of the url

Comment: @Coldtold I tried it but still don't work

Comment: Patrick, if you are saying to @Forte that the js file isn't loaded, then why would you expect it to run?

Comment: Hi, thakns. I post the solution, it seems related with a damage library file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all the validation and unobtrusive js files from the project and reload them from NuGet, and everything got solved.

Thanks for the help.